# Implementation of copyout() in FreeBSD

Tags: unix, freebsd, bsd, netbsd

Where is the definition of function `copyout()` in FreeBSD for AMD64?

(http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/9/copyout/)

The only place I can find is in `sys/sys/systm.h`.

The definition/declaration is:

```
int     copyout(const void * __restrict kaddr, void * __restrict udaddr,
        size_t len) __nonnull(1) __nonnull(2);
```

Is it a declaration or a definition? What does `__nonnull(1)` and `__nonnull(2)` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a function prototype, otherwise known as a *declaration*.  The implementation (*definition* if you choose) is in the kernel sources.  You can find those [online](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/), or (if you chose to install sources) on your local FreeBSD machine (under `/usr/src/sys`).  There are actually several copies, depending on the hardware for which the kernel is compiled.  (The function names, by the way, are "old" — I encountered them in the mid-1980s, and they were well-known at that point in time).

The kernel source contains several implementations of these functions, depending on the hardware platform.  For instance, in FreeBSD 10, the amd64 version is written in assembly language (see SVN in [/usr/src/sys/amd64/amd64/support.S](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/10.0.0/sys/amd64/amd64/support.S?revision=260789&view=markup) for instance).  In the same release, I found only one implementation written in C (under the powerpc subtree), and in current source, *that* has been rewritten.  So, to know "where" is the source, you must do some research and find the corresponding source for your hardware platform and release of FreeBSD.

`__nonnull` is a compiler directive telling it to ensure that the given parameters are not obviously null-pointers.  See for example these mailing list comments:

- [svn commit: r283249 - head/sys/sys](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.freebsd.devel.cvs/527336)
- [Introduce the gcc/clang nonnull attribute in the signal and pthread headers.](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D2101)

Comment: Do you know where is the actual function body of copyout() for AMD64, FreeBSD 10.1? I know it must be in some files, but cannot locate it.

Comment: It's in `sys/amd64/amd64/support.S` , See e.g. here http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/amd64/amd64/support.S#L227

Comment: Any easy way to intercept (record or change the copied bytes) function `copyout()`?  It seems hard to intercept it in the assembly language (%rdi, %rsi, %rdx).

Comment: If you are able to compile your own kernel, you could rename the entrypoints in the `.S` file, and interpose a c-language function that calls the renamed entrypoints.